# How to group similar numpy arrays using Nearest Neighbors or something else

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, similarity, nearest-neighbor

I have multiple pandas dfs (or 2 dimension numpy arrays) with three column.  I will paste some example:

df1 is:

```
date    val1    val2
18893   -0.971  0.256
18894   -0.5596 0.8745
18897   1.273   0.9897
18898   -1.303  -0.955
18899   1.533   0.3203
```

df2 is:

```
date    val1    val2
18893   0.446   1.139
18894   -2.545  1.405
18897   -1.409  0.12195
18898   -0.694  0.3816
18899   -0.2003 0.0714
```

df3 is:

```
date    val1    val2
18893   5.008   0.01563
18894   0.99    0.5244
18897   -2.41   0.1616
18898   2.756   -0.2778
18899   0.7876  -0.4116
```

I have 500+ dataframes. Now I want to cluster them into groups or find similarity between each of them (500x500 similarities).

Comment: You would need to define a criterion for similarity (based on your purpose). Otherwise, you can define various ways to achieve that.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html This is a machine learning clustering problem. Also known as "unsupervised classification". There is a vast literature on the subject, and it is an active area of research today, with new algorithms being made every day. There is no accepted best solution to the problem. To start out - You could use any algorithm from "scikit-learn" to attempt a solution. Some will work better than others, and it won't be obvious which will or will not. It won't even be obvious which one performs better than another.

Comment: check out https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html